# Is idolatrous belief forbidden for gentiles, or is it just practice?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, theology, avodah-zarah, noachide-laws

Suppose a non-Jew believes that there are multiple gods, but he does not worship them in any way. Is this a violation of the prohibition against idolatry for gentiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.moshiach.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=227&Itemid=64 which in turn references *Nodah B'Yehudah, volume 2, Yoreh Deah, number 148*.

> So long as ascribing power to a deity other than the Creator remains conceptual, it is permissible to the Children of Noah according to many authorities. But worship of this independent being is clearly idolatry

Note: I have not checked the Nodah B'Yehudah, and nowhere does it say who wrote the book I copied from, so I hope, but can not be certain, that it's accurately representing what the Nodah B'Yehudah says.

Comment: A famous teshuva of his http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1447&pgnum=187